# How to use Life-ray 7 search engine API's with Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay, liferay-6, elasticsearch-2.0, liferay-7

We are developing a search engine application in Life Ray 7 and Elastic-Search(2.2). I’ve gone through the official documentation of Life-ray 7 API’ for elastic search but it only describes some classes we need to use and very confusing. We are not using elastic search native API and Transport client.

1. How to connect to EL from Life-ray? (We have gone through this [official link](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/introduction-to-liferay-search#indexers)  )
2. How to use life-ray 7 API for indexing and searching in Elastic search?( The [official doc](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/introduction-to-liferay-search#indexers) only mentions some classes for doing this. We can't find a doc to see how to use them, even Javadoc contains nothing)

I really appreciate if someone can provide us a link to a proper tutorial or an example of how to index a document (for ex: a profile object) in Elastic search on localhost.

> We are completely new to the Liferay and elastic search, pardon me for any mistake. Also, we know how to develop the above logics using Native API of elastic search and Java Transport Client.

Answer (score 1):

```
How to connect to EL from Life-ray?
```

This [link](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/configuring-elasticsearch-for-liferay-0) describes the step-by-step process required to setup Liferay with Elastic search.

```
How to use life-ray 7 API for indexing and searching in Elastic search?
```

The API's for search/indexing in Liferay 7.0 hasn't changed much. So, I would suggest referring to this [link](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/implementing-search-and-indexing).

I personally haven't implemented Elastic Search in the past as I have used only GSA in my experience. However, I'm pretty sure this documentation is sufficient to get started.

Comment: Hello YuVi, Thank you for the response. These are the two documents we actually used and described in my question. Liferay 6.2 doc was more clear than 7, we are gonna try using 6.2 docs on Liferay 7

Comment: Good luck with that! Btw, in your question both the link points to 7.0 API.

Comment: Vikki, did you ever get any further with your project? We are evaluating Elasticsearch with Liferay the same as you and information is sparse. Thanks!